# Accessing stateless webservice api in Service fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Im trying out the service fabric demo application provided by Microsoft. 
https://github.com/azure/service-fabric

Ive got it up and running and i have the SF Explorer showing me all services are up and running as well.

I cant manage to reach the web service api though. It has a controller called HomeController and a method called Index (as well as GuestExe, Stateful, Stateless and Actor). In the properties of the WebService it says its URL is http://localhost:2416/ so i try 
http://localhost:2416/Home/Index with a break point set in the index method but i get a "Site cant be reached" error in the browser.

I also try with 
http://localhost:2416/Home/
http://localhost:2416/
http://localhost:2416/Index

How can i figure out the right URL to access this Stateless Service?

Comment: The link you provided just goes to the generic SF GitHub page. Can you share the specific link to the tutorial you followed?

Comment: No tutorial, its just a demo site. Althoug i think MS has some article about it. Ill check it out.

Comment: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-getting-started

Comment: Thanks for that. I cannot seem to get that sample to work either. Not sure if there is a problem with it. We have another .net sample I could get working which might help you get started https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-quickstart-dotnet

Comment: @Micah_MSFT Thanks! Although that example you sent me accesses and retrieves information like actors in a totally different way than in the current Service Fabric documentation and the Pluralsight tutorials ive seen. This is very confusing. There is a lot to read about Service Fabric but it doesnt seem to be coherent. I wonder if its beeing abandonded by Microsoft?

Comment: I really just lack a good working example of the basics, create, save, get and iterate actors and just get a list of all actors.

Comment: We have absolutely not given up on SF. It is one of our star products actually :) We do have an abundance of SF docs and examples. Something like 2000+ I believe. So I can understand it can be difficult to find what you are looking for. I will do some research and see what I can find. Also, since Pluralsite is a 3rd party site some info might not be fully up to date such as you are seeing. What exactly are you looking to learn? I can find docs and examples for you

Comment: @Micah_MSFT Oh that sounds great. Ill PM you.

Comment: Great. I emailed you offline so we can continue the discussion.